# IIS only serve site if cookie exists

Tags: iis, cookies

I have a website that I don't want anyone to be able to access UNLESS... they have a valid HttpOnly cookie in their browser.

So a user logs in at `www.domain.com` and has an httponly cookie set in their browser. Then they get redirected to `dashboard.domain.com` which should show them private stuffs!

But if someone goes directy to `dashboard.domain.com` without first logging in, then they wont have a cookie in their request, and I want IIS to redirect them to the `www` site.

How can I ask IIS to check that a cookie exists (value doesn't matter, it should just exist) before serving a website? Can IIS even do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goal: Redirect user if a cookie is NOT present in their request.

Solution:

- Add to web.config for IIS at root of project
- Assumes cookie is `CookieName=some_value`
- Matching pattern uses regex to check cookie name with any value
- The `negate` property inverts to condition, similar to a NOT operator.
- `redirectType="Found"` is optional and is 302. Default is 301.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="Redirect if Cookie is NOT present" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="CookieName=*" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.my-domain.com" redirectType="Found"/>
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rule is basically a wildcard for a cookie with `CookieName` so that if a cookie with that name has any value at all, this rule wont take effect. But if the cookie does not exist, you will be redirected to another URL.

One caveat is that there's no way to identify an HttpOnly cookie vs a browser-set cookie... :(

Sources:

- [URL Rewrite Module Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS Redirect Module, If the cookie exists, then it will redirect to `dashboard.domain.com`, Here is a example you can use as a reference.

If cookie name is _xx and value is HCjdskfds==, then you rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="redirect based on cookie" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="_xx=HCjdskfds==" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://dashboard.domain.com" />
```

Comment: It looks like this rule is doing the redirect if the cookie DOES exist, but I want the opposite. If you try to access Site A without a cookie, you will be redirected to login at Site B.

Comment: You can try to set HTTP_COOKIE to null.